# is it possible to use ruby vcr gem without passing a block of code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cypress, vcr

I want to use Cypress as a testing tool with the cypress-on-rails plugin.

However during a cypress scenario I want to enable/wrap all rails backend requests with vcr so all requests are captured and replayed.

Typically you would tag a rspec or cucumber file that essentially wraps an entire block of code to perform this. The nature of cypress is that it's completely client/javascript driven and a scenario plays out with multiple ajax requests from the client.

Comment: ...and what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I want vcr to record all http requests server side for each cypress scenario. Hope that helps.

Comment: If you could paste code example where you want to add VCR, it'd be really helpful.

Comment: If you're using Cypress, you're jointly testing the front end and back end, so why would you would you want to mock the back end out? Why not just write unit tests? I second what mrzasa is saying; adding code always clarifies questions. fwiw you can do `VCR.use_cassette("my_requests") { ... }` to have VCR save to `"#{config.cassette_library_dir}/my_requests.yml"`

Comment: Please involve in this issue: https://github.com/shakacode/cypress-on-rails/issues/39

Answer (score 0):

The insert/eject methods on which the `use_cassette` method is built are publicly available.

https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/vcr/VCR#insert_cassette-instance_method

```rb
VCR.insert_cassette('my_cassette')
# do stuff
VCR.eject_cassette
```